# Fade out section on page top, fade in on bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got this codepen: https://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/NpVXRR 
When I scroll the first section fades out and the second one fades in from the bottom with this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".top").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 400);
  });
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".bottom").css("opacity", 0 + $(window).scrollTop() / 400);
  });
```

But that's just a scroll event and only working with 2 sections. Is there a way that I can add more sections and they just fade out, when they reach the top and fade in from the bottom?

Comment: Since top and bottom are classes, couldn't you just reuse those through out your page but on different elements?

Comment: Also, it looks like you could probably combine those into the same window scroll event, so just removing lines 3 and 4 from the example above.

Comment: @LeeWise No, I couldn't. Because it's just a scroll event, other sections would just fade in and out as you start scrolling (so below the other sections), but what I try to achieve is that they fade out on top and fade in on bottom (like in the fiddle of the answer below). And yes, I'm aware that I could combine these 2 functions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want something like this: when an element comes into the viewport area, it's faded in and when it comes out of the viewport area, it should be faded out.

So all the thing should be done in the `onscroll` event of the window. To know if the element is in and out of the viewport area we need to know about its `top` and `bottom` (which can be calculated from its `top` and its `height`), we also need to know about the viewport's height. That's all we need to find out if an element is in or out the viewport area. The following is the detailed code. NOTE: I don't include the complexity of getting the viewport's height here for simplicity (I just use `document.documentElement.clientHeight` - which should work in the latest versions of all modern browsers today).

***HTML***:

```
<div class="fading"></div>
<div class="fading"></div>
<div class="fading"></div>
<div class="fading"></div>
```

***CSS***:

```
.fading {
  border:1px solid red;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  height:500px;
  background:green;
}
```

***JS***:

```
var fadings = $(".fading");
$(window).scroll(function(){
  //the viewport's height
  var vpheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  //loop through all interested elements
  fadings.each(function(){
    //get the rect of the current element
    var r = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    //the current element's height  
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    //check if the element is completely out of the viewport area
    //to just ignore it (save some computation)
    if(thisHeight + r.top < 0 || r.top > vpheight) return true;
    //calculate the opacity for partially visible/hidden element
    var opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, 
                  (r.top >= 0 ? vpheight - r.top : thisHeight - Math.abs(r.top)) / vpheight));
    //set the opacity
    $(this).css("opacity", opacity);
  });           
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dj73n4qk/)

Comment: You are the real "King King"! Works perfectly. But when I change the divs height, `var opacity` doesn't seem to be correct. It jumps from `opacity: 0.9` to `opacity:0.6` for example. Do I have to change some of the math?

Comment: @TobiasGlaus which is the exact value you set for your divs height? Also BTW the current code sets the max opacity of 1 for the divs only when their top edge reaches the top edge of the viewport. So if the divs are totally visible in the viewport but their top edge is still in the middle, their opacity will still be less than 1. Do you want your divs to totally become opaque when it's totally visible (completely contained in the viewport)?

Comment: btw King King here means *very very big in size*

Comment: Didn't know this meaning of "king king" ^.^ But have a look at this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/LWowWX) I literally just copied the code from your fiddle and adjusted the divs height. At the bottom it nicely fades in but on the top it "jumps" to a lower opacity.